# Trying to work on a JS randomizer or something

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
function btn() {
            var words = ['A','B','C','D'],
            div = document.getElementById('foo');
            for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                div.innerHTML += ' ' + words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
            }

        }
```

And I keep getting endless results insted of a certain ammount of different results every time I press the button, can you guys help me?

Comment: what do you mean by "endless results"?

Comment: @dandavis Because of `+=`, each time he runs it the results keep getting longer and longer, instead of replacing the previous results.

Comment: @DavidConrad: it only adds one char each time, not sure what you mean...

Comment: @dandavis Yes, but nothing ever clears the div. Presumably there's a button on the page that calls this function. Imagine clicking that several times in succession. Now imagine you expected only 10 random characters each time.

Comment: @DavidConrad: you're so smart.  OP: add `div.innerHTML="";` before the loop

Comment: But I only get 1 result now :(

Comment: @MarcoGutksigkartoffelmenschen You don't want all the results -- you don't want ONE result.  What, *exactly* do you want -- and without being rude, I'm going to have to emphasize the *exactly*.

Comment: Lol, sorry for not explaining that so clearly, I want 10 results, now I only get 1, and before, each time I pressed the button on the page it kept adding 10 results making like 10 20 30 40... hope that's more comprehensive, sorry.

Comment: @dandavis said to add the code *before the loop* (eg between the `div` line and the `for` line); you appear to have added it inside the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what your trouble is.  I created a snippet from your example and ran it... I'm getting fairly random output in the console.

Now, I did modify your function so it returns a value rather than updating the HTML.  Decoupling the logic (the random generation) from the presentation (showing it to the user) makes testing code *much* easier.

```js
function btn() {
  var words = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
  
  var result = "";
  
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    result += ' ' + words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
  }
  
  console.log('result = ', result);
  return result;
}


document.getElementById("generate").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = btn();
  });
```

```html
The random output is here: <div id="result"></div>

<button id="generate" type="button">Click to generate a new random string</button>
```

Comment: I'm a noob, how do I get it to shot on html again?

Comment: Like the guys above said if I click the button several times in succession it keeps adding 10+ results.

Comment: The only thing now is: The results tend to repeat like AABCCD, in the previous it didn't, any chance to get that fixed?

Comment: @MarcoGutksigkartoffelmenschen in the example I post, they don't repeat.